# After installing Ubuntu 12.04 pc goes in GRUB rescue

Tags: 12.04, grub2

As a part of my school lab I did following:

- Starting off with win 7 installed
- Installed 10.04 in remaining space > worked
- Installed 12.04 in amother partition I created finished installation took out the disk.

After the 12.04 the system booted into Grub rescue mode.
I didnt know what to do as I never used ubuntu so I just moved on to install 14.04 as part of lab hoping the previous grub loader problem will be solved then, by replacing Grub from CD.

After the 14.04 installation I still get the Grub resuce prompt.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong your system has three  operating system one is windows 7 and other is two different version of Ubuntu.I think your **boot loader** may not be installed in the same drive where your Ubuntu is installed, if it is not then do the following steps.

1.Use the live CD to check which partitions exists on your hd.

2.Mount your Linux partition

3.**(Re)Install** Grub.

4.Reboot your system.

Comment: Yeah I got 4 .. One win7 and than Ubuntu 10.04 12.04 and 14.04 ..and I got all of them in different partition .but as mentioned after installing Ubuntu 12.04 in partition I wanted computer didn't load grub to select what os I want and instead gone in grub rescue . So must be boot didn't got installed properly .will do what you Said and post it back what happens ..thanks you so much